# No handler found for URI (elasticsearch)

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Im trying to add type to index like this:

```
PUT /catalog/_mapping/product
    {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type":"text"
        }
      }
    }
```

In answer I get an error:

```
{
  "error" : "no handler found for uri [/catalog/_mapping/product?pretty=true] and method [PUT]"
}
```

The same situation in CURL. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 8):

I assume you use ElasticSearch 8.x version.

From ElasticSearch 8.x version, only **_doc** is supported and it is just an endpoint name, not a document type. So try with:

```
PUT /catalog/_doc/product
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type":"text"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to specify anything after `_mapping` since there can only be a single mapping type in an index mapping.

So simply like this will work:

```
PUT /catalog/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type":"text"
    }
  }
}
```